# capturing stdout from python in an upstart job

Tags: python, stdout, upstart

I'm struggling to save the stdout output of a python2.6 script into a file when I run it as an upstart job.

This is my current test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from time import sleep
import sys

while 1:
    print "Hello from stdout"
    print >> sys.stderr, "Hello from stderr"
    sleep(1)
```

if I do `$ myscript >> /var/log/myscript` that works fine. I see both.

However, as an upstart script, if I use the following conf

1. /etc/init/myscript.conf:

   ```
   exec /path/to/myscript >> /var/log/myscript 2>&1
   ```

   I see this:

   ```
   Hello from stderr
   Hello from stderr
   Hello from stderr
   Hello from stderr
   Hello from stderr
   Hello from stderr
   ```

If I use a different file for stderr and stdout, they are both created, but the stdout is always empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffering and flushing would be the guess.

stderr is typically an unbuffered stream while stdout is buffered.  When you send it to a file it will be buffered in 4k chunks (typically).

If you make the following change:

```
while 1:
    print "hello from stdout"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print >> sys.stderr, "Hello from stderr"
    sleep(1)
```

You should see output in your file.

Comment: I thought it might be a buffering issue. I had assumed that when python receives a SIGTERM, it would flush stdout itself.

I guess a potential solution to this is to capture SIGTERM and to flush the buffer at that point.

Comment: Yes, handling sigterm with a flush() will get what you want.  A TERM if not handled will terminate the program, though an interesting thought to have the default handler flush all IO...